# How to check if the field TFK is maintained in the table

Tags: abap

I am trying to display an error message for certain conditions. The goal is that from table COST, for an object number (that contains TEST + cost center + activity type), gjahr, value type(WRTTP) and version(VERSN), to check if for a certain fixed price per unit measure(TFK001-016) there is data in the table. Thus, if TFKXXX is not maintained in the COST table it will show an error message.

Now what I have done, is using a Call Function, to get the three number period for the TFK field, thus based on the exporting parameter of date/monmit/periv we will get the field of lv_poper which is the period. Then I have done a merge of TFK and lv_poper. Now what I want to do is to check whether a TFK001-016 field is maintained for the key parameters. I cannot do `<ls_co_data>-lv_tfkxxx` as it does not exist in the table COST. Does anyone have any idea on how can I check if the field TFK001-016 is maintained in the table COST?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'DATE_TO_PERIOD_CONVERT'
    EXPORTING
      i_date         = lv_date
      i_monmit       = lv_monmit
      i_periv        = lv_periv
    IMPORTING
      e_buper        = lv_poper
      e_gjahr        = lv_gjahr
    EXCEPTIONS
      input_false    = 1
      t009_notfound  = 2
      t009b_notfound = 3
      OTHERS         = 4.


lv_objnr = 'TEST' +  <ls_co_data>-send_cctr + <ls_co_data>-acttype.

lv_tkfxxx = 'TKF' + lv_poper.


    LOOP AT lt_cost ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_cost>)
                         WHERE objnr = lv_objnr
                          AND gjahr = lv_gjahr
                          AND wrttp = 1
                          AND versn = 0.

      IF lv_tkfxxx IS NOT INITIAL. "The lv_tkfxxx should be checked in the cost table

        lv_text = 'Not maintained in ' +  lv_objnr + ' for the date ' + <ls_co_data>-postgdate.

      ENDIF.

    ENDLOOP.
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: In TFK001-016, is TFK001 a structure for period 001 with a field called 016? Or is the  structure just TFK001 and there are fields for periods of which 016 is one?

Comment: what is `TFK001-016`? which value lays in `lv_poper`? what value lays in your `TFK001` field? give the sample input and the expected output, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

```
LOOP AT lt_cost ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_cost>)
  WHERE objnr = lv_objnr
    AND gjahr = lv_gjahr
    AND wrttp = 1
    AND versn = 0.

    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_tkfxxx OF STRUCTURE <ls_cost> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<v_tkfxxx>).
    IF sy-subrc = 0 AND <v_tkfxxx> IS NOT INITIAL. 
      lv_text = 'Not maintained in ' +  lv_objnr + ' for the date ' + <ls_co_data>-postgdate.
    ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```